# sql exposure of a product over dates

Tags: sql, distinct, validates-uniqueness-of

I have a table with the following data

```
ProductID          StartDate     EndDate
TT1                1 May 2013    10 May 2013
TT1                8 May 2013    14 May 2013
TT2                6 May 2013    12 May 2013
TT2                8 May 2013    12 May 2013
```

The result needs to show the following count

```
TT1               14  (Note this is the 10 days from the 1 record and the 11,12,13,14 May)
TT2               7   (Note this for the 6-12 rec
```

Comment: This is a zero effort question

Comment: This is condensing-set question, and there are multiple examples on this site.  Be warned, these can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT productID,DATEDIFF(MAX(endDate),MIN(startDate))+1 DAYS FROM
   db.new_table GROUP BY productID
```